# Airflow server constantly restarting - Signal 15

Tags: airflow

I launch a airflow webserver command in my local machine to start an airflow instance on port 8081. The server starts, however the pŕompt constantly shows some warning messages, as a loop. No error message appears, but the server doesn't works. Those are the messages:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/airflow/configuration.py:361 DeprecationWarning: The default_queue option in [celery] has been moved to the default_queue option in [operators] - the old setting has been used, but please update your config.
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/airflow/configuration.py:361 DeprecationWarning: The dag_concurrency option in [core] has been renamed to max_active_tasks_per_dag - the old setting has been used, but please update your config.
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/airflow/configuration.py:361 DeprecationWarning: The processor_poll_interval option in [scheduler] has been renamed to scheduler_idle_sleep_time - the old setting has been used, but please update your config.
[2022-06-13 15:11:57,355] {manager.py:779} WARNING - No user yet created, use flask fab command to do it.
[2022-06-13 15:12:01,925] {manager.py:512} WARNING - Refused to delete permission view, assoc with role exists DAG Runs.can_create User
[2022-06-13 15:12:19 +0000] [1117638] [INFO] Handling signal: ttou
[2022-06-13 15:12:19 +0000] [1120256] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 1120256)
[2022-06-13 15:12:19 +0000] [1117638] [WARNING] Worker with pid 1120256 was terminated due to signal 15
[2022-06-13 15:12:22 +0000] [1117638] [INFO] Handling signal: ttin
[2022-06-13 15:12:22 +0000] [1121568] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1121568
```

Do you know what can could be happening?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you share more details about which version of Airflow you are using, How you have installed it?

Comment: might be related to the warning "No user yet created...", run the following in your terminal :  FLASK_APP=airflow.www.app flask fab create-admin

Comment: I would recommend to try running Airflow in an isolated Docker container instead. There could be too many dependency conflicts and local machine configurations that could affect when running it locally.